# How to make AppStorage Variable only available when running on iOS 14?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, uikit, ios14

I am going nuts I want to use AppStorage only available in iOS 14 (to use it in Widgets)! But I get a Error:

> Property wrappers are not yet supported on local properties

I want to integrate the widget in my UIKit App, will be property wrappers available in the future?

For now my nasty Workaround I am making the whole ViewController @available(iOS 14.0, *), but you guessed it now it runs only on iOS 14!

```
@AppStorage("incomeTotal", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.de.davidkoenig.SimpleMoney"))
var incomeTotal: String = "0.0"
```

Above you see my code for the AppStorage.

Maybe you can help me!?

Comment: If your project is set support iOS below 14 then you would have to use App Groups to manage that or place lots of @available in your project.

Comment: I use app groups, but how to use AppStorage in UIKit and swift file, because the widget needs AppStorage. maybe you know how to setup app groups (userdefaults) in UIKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do safe the object in UIKit:

```
UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.de.davidkoenig.SimpleMoney")!.set(String(format: "%.2f", sumBalance), forKey: "balanceTotal")
```

This works and in my SwiftUI file I use the code in my question!

Comment: I'd recommend you to use an enum instead of a string for the key

Answer (score 0):

There are `UserDefault` custom property wrappers and they work at least in iOS 13:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

Example of `UserDefault` implementation:

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/appstorage-explained/

So `@AppStorage` is available in iOS 14+ but you can create you custom property wrapper. Or do you need some specific features `@AppStorage` provides?